# Can't getting links in google maps v3 to open marker infowindows

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a problem getting links in google maps v3 to open marker infowindows.

Can anyone help with this please.

Code is here:  http://pastebin.com/PgTtzdBq

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html) (translated to v3 from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial.

[v2 example using dropdown](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map15c.htm), same concept applies to v3 (a dropdown is not API version specific)

Comment: Hi, I've looked at that but I can't get it to work with the dropdown box.

Comment: No dropdown box mentioned in your question.  Will add a link to Mike's v2 example using a dropdown

Comment: The dropdown contains a list of counties/states. When one is select it zooms to that county and the sidebar lists the markers for that county. But I can't open any of the markers listed in the sidebar, when I click on them.

Comment: What have you tried to make them clickable?  A live link to your map might make it possible to see what you are talking about and make additional suggestions.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a live link. But if you look at http://http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html All I need here is to replace the tick boxes with a dropdown and have it work the same. I added a dropdown to that code but couldn't figure out how to get it to work like the tick boxes.

Comment: Post your version where you tried that (replacing the checkboxes with a dropdown) in a jsfiddle so someone can tell you what you did wrong.